# quo and enquo in dplyr style function, Error in ~Sessions : object 'Sessions' not found

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
dput(dat.trended)
structure(list(date = structure(c(18230, 18230, 18230, 18230, 
18230, 18230, 18230, 18230, 18231, 18231, 18231, 18231, 18231, 
18231, 18231, 18231, 18232, 18232, 18232, 18232, 18232, 18232, 
18232, 18233, 18233, 18233, 18233, 18233, 18233, 18233, 18234, 
18234, 18234, 18234, 18234, 18234, 18234, 18235, 18235, 18235, 
18235, 18235, 18235, 18235, 18236, 18236, 18236, 18236, 18236, 
18236, 18236, 18237, 18237, 18237, 18237, 18237, 18237, 18237, 
18237, 18238, 18238, 18238, 18238, 18238, 18238, 18238, 18238, 
18239, 18239, 18239, 18239, 18239, 18239, 18239, 18239, 18240, 
18240, 18240, 18240, 18240, 18240, 18240, 18240, 18241, 18241, 
18241, 18241, 18241, 18241, 18241, 18241, 18242, 18242, 18242, 
18242, 18242, 18242, 18242, 18242, 18243, 18243, 18243, 18243, 
18243, 18243, 18243, 18243, 18244, 18244, 18244, 18244, 18244, 
18244, 18244, 18244, 18245, 18245, 18245, 18245, 18245, 18245, 
18245, 18245, 18246, 18246, 18246, 18246, 18246, 18246, 18246, 
18246, 18247, 18247, 18247, 18247, 18247, 18247, 18247, 18247, 
18247, 18248, 18248, 18248, 18248, 18248, 18248, 18248, 18248, 
18248, 18249, 18249, 18249, 18249, 18249, 18249, 18249, 18249, 
18250, 18250, 18250, 18250, 18250, 18250, 18250, 18250, 18250, 
18251, 18251, 18251, 18251, 18251, 18251, 18251, 18251, 18252, 
18252, 18252, 18252, 18252, 18252, 18252, 18252, 18253, 18253, 
18253, 18253, 18253, 18253, 18253, 18254, 18254, 18254, 18254, 
18254, 18254, 18254, 18254, 18255, 18255, 18255, 18255, 18255, 
18255, 18255, 18255, 18256, 18256, 18256, 18256, 18256, 18256, 
18256, 18256, 18257, 18257, 18257, 18257, 18257, 18257, 18257, 
18257, 18258, 18258, 18258, 18258, 18258, 18258, 18258, 18258
), class = "Date"), Channel = c("(Other)", "Direct", "Display", 
"Email", "Organic Search", "Paid Search", "Referral", "Social", 
"(Other)", "Direct", "Display", "Email", "Organic Search", "Paid Search", 
"Referral", "Social", "(Other)", "Direct", "Email", "Organic Search", 
"Paid Search", "Referral", "Social", "(Other)", "Direct", "Email", 
"Organic Search", "Paid Search", "Referral", "Social", "(Other)", 
"Direct", "Email", "Organic Search", "Paid Search", "Referral", 
"Social", "(Other)", "Direct", "Email", "Organic Search", "Paid Search", 
"Referral", "Social", "(Other)", "Direct", "Email", "Organic Search", 
"Paid Search", "Referral", "Social", "(Other)", "Direct", "Display", 
"Email", "Organic Search", "Paid Search", "Referral", "Social", 
"(Other)", "Direct", "Display", "Email", "Organic Search", "Paid Search", 
"Referral", "Social", "(Other)", "Affiliates", "Direct", "Email", 
"Organic Search", "Paid Search", "Referral", "Social", "(Other)", 
"Direct", "Display", "Email", "Organic Search", "Paid Search", 
"Referral", "Social", "(Other)", "Direct", "Display", "Email", 
"Organic Search", "Paid Search", "Referral", "Social", "(Other)", 
"Direct", "Display", "Email", "Organic Search", "Paid Search", 
"Referral", "Social", "(Other)", "Direct", "Display", "Email", 
"Organic Search", "Paid Search", "Referral", "Social", "(Other)", 
"Direct", "Display", "Email", "Organic Search", "Paid Search", 
"Referral", "Social", "(Other)", "Direct", "Display", "Email", 
"Organic Search", "Paid Search", "Referral", "Social", "(Other)", 
"Direct", "Display", "Email", "Organic Search", "Paid Search", 
"Referral", "Social", "(Other)", "Affiliates", "Direct", "Display", 
"Email", "Organic Search", "Paid Search", "Referral", "Social", 
"(Other)", "Affiliates", "Direct", "Display", "Email", "Organic Search", 
"Paid Search", "Referral", "Social", "(Other)", "Direct", "Display", 
"Email", "Organic Search", "Paid Search", "Referral", "Social", 
"(Other)", "Affiliates", "Direct", "Display", "Email", "Organic Search", 
"Paid Search", "Referral", "Social", "(Other)", "Direct", "Display", 
"Email", "Organic Search", "Paid Search", "Referral", "Social", 
"(Other)", "Direct", "Display", "Email", "Organic Search", "Paid Search", 
"Referral", "Social", "(Other)", "Direct", "Email", "Organic Search", 
"Paid Search", "Referral", "Social", "(Other)", "Direct", "Display", 
"Email", "Organic Search", "Paid Search", "Referral", "Social", 
"(Other)", "Direct", "Display", "Email", "Organic Search", "Paid Search", 
"Referral", "Social", "(Other)", "Direct", "Display", "Email", 
"Organic Search", "Paid Search", "Referral", "Social", "(Other)", 
"Direct", "Display", "Email", "Organic Search", "Paid Search", 
"Referral", "Social", "(Other)", "Direct", "Display", "Email", 
"Organic Search", "Paid Search", "Referral", "Social"), DailyUsers = c(4584, 
122507, 1, 790, 36015, 733, 22716, 44639, 5107, 136612, 1, 773, 
41964, 808, 26301, 53908, 6613, 180241, 1330, 48477, 907, 32545, 
54564, 6776, 166011, 1782, 46269, 900, 29584, 49245, 6716, 175636, 
1061, 44079, 925, 27302, 46499, 6122, 169174, 1159, 43812, 836, 
27814, 43787, 5499, 151641, 796, 40171, 755, 25464, 41112, 4568, 
128915, 1, 540, 36766, 789, 23039, 41885, 5205, 143873, 2, 633, 
42361, 802, 26525, 51519, 7005, 1, 179617, 868, 48641, 915, 33230, 
55982, 7247, 172763, 1, 927, 45502, 834, 29853, 49680, 6629, 
163548, 10, 1102, 42964, 773, 27673, 46432, 6774, 158663, 9, 
1313, 41267, 764, 26924, 41696, 5868, 146750, 11, 661, 38098, 
758, 24081, 38489, 4575, 121006, 6, 482, 34642, 737, 21416, 40289, 
4616, 135709, 7, 562, 38238, 815, 24560, 45485, 7468, 172483, 
4, 780, 44160, 780, 30592, 45159, 6908, 1, 160183, 10, 714, 41889, 
784, 26831, 41552, 6330, 1, 150554, 10, 898, 38073, 704, 25583, 
36881, 5495, 145060, 8, 673, 35519, 722, 22461, 34739, 5237, 
1, 142440, 10, 874, 32385, 645, 21154, 33666, 4061, 112273, 8, 
381, 29598, 675, 17570, 32665, 3888, 106445, 1, 368, 30830, 686, 
18249, 35123, 4531, 120502, 1195, 31502, 701, 19681, 34551, 3603, 
95447, 1, 577, 23994, 576, 14703, 26813, 2507, 83464, 2, 324, 
21731, 595, 12008, 22082, 2867, 98924, 1, 361, 28706, 717, 15739, 
27070, 2519, 110161, 3, 327, 30031, 709, 16066, 28716, 2135, 
101149, 2, 286, 28501, 743, 14617, 30129), Sessions = c(5662, 
140831, 1, 964, 41266, 769, 28090, 48214, 6258, 157435, 1, 976, 
48872, 850, 32734, 58368, 8263, 206339, 1616, 56362, 936, 41013, 
60134, 8475, 189989, 2003, 52984, 952, 36599, 53858, 8271, 198848, 
1335, 50233, 955, 33893, 50887, 7693, 191770, 1370, 49736, 864, 
34287, 47590, 6901, 172475, 1003, 45772, 800, 31295, 44571, 5704, 
148088, 1, 656, 42294, 822, 28452, 45226, 6607, 165534, 2, 801, 
49337, 858, 32962, 56008, 8686, 1, 205329, 1066, 56373, 950, 
41401, 61180, 8974, 197191, 1, 1116, 52376, 887, 37316, 54398, 
8328, 186861, 10, 1282, 48913, 817, 34246, 50714, 8269, 180251, 
9, 1521, 46949, 810, 33109, 45453, 7272, 167272, 11, 836, 43257, 
806, 29710, 41932, 5728, 139022, 6, 603, 39619, 787, 26441, 43352, 
5900, 155182, 7, 683, 44232, 853, 30398, 49342, 10388, 217068, 
4, 1049, 54970, 850, 40829, 53278, 8685, 1, 182160, 10, 882, 
47799, 826, 33132, 45484, 7794, 1, 170454, 10, 1033, 43464, 726, 
31096, 40310, 6677, 163956, 8, 851, 40376, 753, 27458, 37682, 
6324, 1, 159839, 10, 1011, 36577, 685, 25788, 36395, 5010, 127954, 
8, 499, 33887, 690, 21511, 35205, 4752, 121747, 1, 460, 35583, 
725, 22589, 37848, 5539, 137528, 1381, 36278, 728, 24421, 37487, 
4505, 109400, 1, 692, 27551, 630, 17949, 28790, 3074, 94643, 
2, 395, 24511, 633, 14542, 23327, 6888, 222318, 2, 888, 63947, 
1486, 37906, 57280, 3092, 122398, 3, 407, 33506, 768, 19062, 
30477, 2625, 112959, 3, 375, 31670, 812, 17500, 31946), Transactions = c(24, 
614, 0, 39, 73, 0, 1781, 75, 29, 898, 0, 50, 104, 0, 2205, 125, 
46, 1161, 84, 117, 0, 2822, 125, 64, 779, 63, 74, 0, 2081, 91, 
92, 610, 68, 72, 0, 1798, 130, 36, 637, 60, 95, 0, 1893, 91, 
33, 523, 49, 78, 0, 1698, 78, 18, 496, 0, 41, 50, 0, 1412, 78, 
31, 751, 0, 43, 99, 0, 2041, 122, 30, 0, 856, 54, 118, 0, 2441, 
128, 35, 779, 0, 45, 97, 0, 2124, 113, 40, 779, 0, 43, 101, 0, 
1884, 112, 34, 671, 0, 37, 79, 0, 1952, 102, 27, 604, 0, 35, 
76, 0, 1635, 77, 29, 506, 0, 30, 72, 0, 1391, 67, 30, 667, 0, 
39, 104, 0, 1785, 91, 74, 1125, 0, 50, 110, 0, 2219, 108, 38, 
0, 639, 0, 38, 70, 0, 1764, 86, 30, 0, 550, 0, 35, 66, 0, 1475, 
70, 42, 487, 0, 32, 61, 0, 1334, 56, 24, 0, 422, 0, 27, 39, 0, 
1159, 57, 16, 345, 0, 32, 47, 0, 935, 63, 9, 366, 0, 21, 44, 
0, 908, 53, 26, 413, 19, 44, 0, 1040, 50, 19, 252, 0, 17, 20, 
0, 623, 42, 8, 155, 0, 16, 18, 0, 468, 21, 22, 448, 0, 30, 44, 
0, 1332, 64, 12, 242, 0, 27, 39, 0, 684, 32, 7, 192, 0, 17, 34, 
0, 695, 28), Revenue = c(1739.74331, 31113.4098, 0, 2312.482089, 
4707.59151, 0, 82485.8405, 3342.691127, 1471.14892, 52576.42497, 
0, 4527.28196, 5729.90202, 0, 103926.5696, 4292.44231, 3521.7898, 
62665.81251, 6011.545189, 7449.704978, 0, 144009.60402, 5953.210453, 
1577.87009, 38261.10011, 2694.018798, 4000.98632, 0, 96847.5706, 
3309.47883, 1701.177895, 27902.17329, 2951.83414, 2971.27577, 
0, 76756.6602, 3515.29931, 2764.4399, 30351.32437, 4789.010241, 
5144.50085, 0, 82277.59305, 2958.273109, 1959.03252, 28802.46538, 
3031.68041, 3586.315, 0, 73028.73399, 3240.188819, 439.617731, 
22872.02071, 0, 2676.741934, 2176.79642, 0, 61351.30115, 2989.81603, 
851.234387, 36528.76585, 0, 2841.349662, 4151.194286, 0, 89709.3116, 
4359.76453, 778.43277, 0, 36356.39973, 2516.140702, 5155.146913, 
0, 96324.67089, 4357.012963, 1772.90713, 35896.53789, 0, 1941.54086, 
4323.53325, 0, 93397.92809, 3192.625251, 1461.7126, 28900.90783, 
0, 1916.5007105, 4841.32437, 0, 85239.33652, 5585.45811, 2275.3234222, 
28425.09616, 0, 1423.95997, 3500.040202, 0, 78402.95617, 2992.36592, 
839.113369, 24428.0301, 0, 2660.20427, 3219.88335, 0, 77911.54692, 
3649.76663, 952.832833, 20949.3076, 0, 1694.55981, 3402.67867, 
0, 60677.01657, 3507.35016, 790.85074, 28618.47916, 0, 2127.7198902, 
4998.198504, 0, 74267.3436, 3810.81114, 1593.180049, 39967.90885, 
0, 2043.741553, 4707.7458188, 0, 96546.4659, 3873.8297254, 1152.759991, 
0, 30586.18438, 0, 2263.76183, 3255.65978, 0, 74831.96684, 2302.93888, 
1541.0201, 0, 25838.51692, 0, 1564.607309, 2585.175407, 0, 56909.35993, 
1893.008107, 3125.484002, 20030.02974, 0, 2984.73174, 2053.920653, 
0, 54000.0694, 2391.062841, 994.023615, 0, 15894.98859, 0, 1587.93677, 
2574.329865, 0, 47319.38721, 1635.377802, 1541.12045, 13794.50411, 
0, 1865.84062, 1858.920211, 0, 37858.94079, 1723.849722, 284.334126, 
15552.58137, 0, 1233.98682, 2079.841952, 0, 34436.41117, 982.248295, 
1098.275799, 14903.710499, 697.91002, 1222.725965, 0, 33794.59734, 
1959.086548, 461.12527, 11560.703802, 0, 1007.17398, 596.599993, 
0, 22088.53336, 1142.67293, 135.400002, 6869.02614, 0, 673.31943, 
1630.839026, 0, 18944.7318, 1252.02348, 1150.00001, 20721.64957, 
0, 1893.8333, 989.919695, 0, 59597.87949, 2347.95408, 605.82993, 
8630.90537, 0, 1581.627411, 2021.417672, 0, 28167.96098, 1222.06059, 
409.939999, 9957.808578, 0, 705.67002, 1168.074171, 0, 31991.812556, 
1061.337995)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-229L))
```

I am attempting to make a function and have ben reading this [dplyr post](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) on how to make functions.

My attempt:

```
metricTables <- function(df, dim, metric) {

  dim <- enquo(dim)
  metric <- enquo(metric)

  df %>% mutate(date = ordered(
    format(date, "%d-%b"),
    levels = format(sort(unique(date)), "%d-%b")
  )) %>% 
    group_by(date, !! dim) %>% 
    summarise(metric = sum(!! metric)) %>% # here I would like the name of the sum(metric) to be the same string that was provided for metric whent he function was called
    gather(Key, value, -!! metric, -date) %>% 
    spread(date, Value) %>% 
    select(-Key) %>% 
    replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(-!! dim), round, 0) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(-!! dim), scales::comma)    
}
```

When I use this code outside of a function, it works as expected, e.g.:

```
# works
    # sessions table
    sessionsTable <- dat.trended %>%
        mutate(date = ordered(
            format(date, "%d-%b"),
            levels = format(sort(unique(date)), "%d-%b")
        )) %>%
        group_by(date, Channel) %>%
        summarise(Sessions = sum(Sessions)) %>%
        gather(Key, Value, -Channel, -date) %>%
        spread(date, Value) %>%
        select(-Key) %>%
        replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
        mutate_at(vars(-Channel), round, 0) %>% 
        mutate_at(vars(-Channel), scales::comma)
```

However when running as a function I get an error:

```
> metricTables(dat.trended, Channel, Sessions)
 Error in ~Sessions : object 'Sessions' not found
```

dat.trended is the data frame I provided above.

Expected output:

```
sessionsTable <- dat.trended %>%
    mutate(date = ordered(
        format(date, "%d-%b"),
        levels = format(sort(unique(date)), "%d-%b")
    )) %>%
    group_by(date, Channel) %>%
    summarise(Sessions = sum(Sessions)) %>%
    gather(Key, Value, -Channel, -date) %>%
    spread(date, Value) %>%
    select(-Key) %>%
    replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(-Channel), round, 0) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(-Channel), scales::comma)
> glimpse(sessionsTable)
Observations: 9
Variables: 30
$ Channel  <chr> "(Other)", "Affiliates", "Direct", "Display", "Email", "Organic Search", "Paid Search", "Referral", …
$ `30-Nov` <chr> "5,662.0", "0.0", "140,831.0", "1.0", "964.0", "41,266.0", "769.0", "28,090.0", "48,214.0"
$ `01-Dec` <chr> "6,258.0", "0.0", "157,435.0", "1.0", "976.0", "48,872.0", "850.0", "32,734.0", "58,368.0"
$ `02-Dec` <chr> "8,263", "0", "206,339", "0", "1,616", "56,362", "936", "41,013", "60,134"
$ `03-Dec` <chr> "8,475", "0", "189,989", "0", "2,003", "52,984", "952", "36,599", "53,858"
$ `04-Dec` <chr> "8,271", "0", "198,848", "0", "1,335", "50,233", "955", "33,893", "50,887"
$ `05-Dec` <chr> "7,693", "0", "191,770", "0", "1,370", "49,736", "864", "34,287", "47,590"
$ `06-Dec` <chr> "6,901", "0", "172,475", "0", "1,003", "45,772", "800", "31,295", "44,571"
$ `07-Dec` <chr> "5,704.0", "0.0", "148,088.0", "1.0", "656.0", "42,294.0", "822.0", "28,452.0", "45,226.0"
$ `08-Dec` <chr> "6,607.0", "0.0", "165,534.0", "2.0", "801.0", "49,337.0", "858.0", "32,962.0", "56,008.0"
$ `09-Dec` <chr> "8,686.0", "1.0", "205,329.0", "0.0", "1,066.0", "56,373.0", "950.0", "41,401.0", "61,180.0"
$ `10-Dec` <chr> "8,974.0", "0.0", "197,191.0", "1.0", "1,116.0", "52,376.0", "887.0", "37,316.0", "54,398.0"
$ `11-Dec` <chr> "8,328", "0", "186,861", "10", "1,282", "48,913", "817", "34,246", "50,714"
$ `12-Dec` <chr> "8,269.0", "0.0", "180,251.0", "9.0", "1,521.0", "46,949.0", "810.0", "33,109.0", "45,453.0"
$ `13-Dec` <chr> "7,272", "0", "167,272", "11", "836", "43,257", "806", "29,710", "41,932"
$ `14-Dec` <chr> "5,728.0", "0.0", "139,022.0", "6.0", "603.0", "39,619.0", "787.0", "26,441.0", "43,352.0"
$ `15-Dec` <chr> "5,900.0", "0.0", "155,182.0", "7.0", "683.0", "44,232.0", "853.0", "30,398.0", "49,342.0"
$ `16-Dec` <chr> "10,388.0", "0.0", "217,068.0", "4.0", "1,049.0", "54,970.0", "850.0", "40,829.0", "53,278.0"
$ `17-Dec` <chr> "8,685.0", "1.0", "182,160.0", "10.0", "882.0", "47,799.0", "826.0", "33,132.0", "45,484.0"
$ `18-Dec` <chr> "7,794.0", "1.0", "170,454.0", "10.0", "1,033.0", "43,464.0", "726.0", "31,096.0", "40,310.0"
$ `19-Dec` <chr> "6,677.0", "0.0", "163,956.0", "8.0", "851.0", "40,376.0", "753.0", "27,458.0", "37,682.0"
$ `20-Dec` <chr> "6,324.0", "1.0", "159,839.0", "10.0", "1,011.0", "36,577.0", "685.0", "25,788.0", "36,395.0"
$ `21-Dec` <chr> "5,010.0", "0.0", "127,954.0", "8.0", "499.0", "33,887.0", "690.0", "21,511.0", "35,205.0"
$ `22-Dec` <chr> "4,752.0", "0.0", "121,747.0", "1.0", "460.0", "35,583.0", "725.0", "22,589.0", "37,848.0"
$ `23-Dec` <chr> "5,539", "0", "137,528", "0", "1,381", "36,278", "728", "24,421", "37,487"
$ `24-Dec` <chr> "4,505.0", "0.0", "109,400.0", "1.0", "692.0", "27,551.0", "630.0", "17,949.0", "28,790.0"
$ `25-Dec` <chr> "3,074.0", "0.0", "94,643.0", "2.0", "395.0", "24,511.0", "633.0", "14,542.0", "23,327.0"
$ `26-Dec` <chr> "6,888.0", "0.0", "222,318.0", "2.0", "888.0", "63,947.0", "1,486.0", "37,906.0", "57,280.0"
$ `27-Dec` <chr> "3,092.0", "0.0", "122,398.0", "3.0", "407.0", "33,506.0", "768.0", "19,062.0", "30,477.0"
$ `28-Dec` <chr> "2,625.0", "0.0", "112,959.0", "3.0", "375.0", "31,670.0", "812.0", "17,500.0", "31,946.0"
```

How can I get my function `metricTables()` to correctly evaluate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, we can convert to string for 'metric' and use `:=`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
metricTables <- function(df, dim, metric) {

     dim <- enquo(dim)
     metric <- enquo(metric)


     df %>% mutate(date = ordered(
       format(date, "%d-%b"),
       levels = format(sort(unique(date)), "%d-%b")
     )) %>% 
       group_by(date, !! dim) %>% 
       summarise(!! rlang::as_name(metric) := sum(!! metric))  %>%
       pivot_longer(cols = -c(date, !!dim), names_to = 'Key', values_to = 'value') %>%
       pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = value) %>%
       select(-Key) %>% 
           replace(is.na(.), 0)  %>%
       mutate_at(vars(- !!rlang::as_name(dim)), round, 0) %>% 
       mutate_at(vars(- !!rlang::as_name(dim)), scales::comma)

 }


metricTables(dat.trended, Channel, Sessions)
```

---

Can also make use of `curly-curly` operator (`{{...}}`)

```
metricTables <- function(df, dim, metric) {




    df %>% 
        mutate(date = ordered(
        format(date, "%d-%b"),
        levels = format(sort(unique(date)), "%d-%b")
      )) %>% 
        group_by(date, {{dim}}) %>% 
        summarise(!! rlang::ensym(metric) := sum({{metric}}))  %>%
        pivot_longer(cols = -c(date, {{dim}}), names_to = 'Key', values_to = 'value')  %>%
        pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = value) %>%
        select(-Key) %>% 
                  replace(is.na(.), 0)  %>%
              mutate_at(vars(- !!rlang::ensym(dim)), round, 0) %>% 
              mutate_at(vars(- !!rlang::ensym(dim)), scales::comma)


  }


 metricTables(dat.trended, Channel, Sessions)
```